# Deterimine concrete type without explicit matching

Tags: scala, generic-programming, shapeless

I am trying to make this DRYer:

```
type CollectPredicate = PartialFunction[Option[SqlArgument], SQLActionBuilder]

val cp: CollectPredicate = {
    case Some(lc: LanguageCode) => buildSql(lc)
    case Some(bh: BlobHashs) => buildSql(bh)
    case Some(lsi: LastSeenId) => buildSql(lsi)
  }
```

I want to find a way to do something like:

```
type args = LanguageCode :+:  BlobHashs :+: LastSeenId :+: CNil

val PlacesRequestType = Coproduct[args]

val cp  =  (sq: args) => buildSql(PlacesRequestType(sql))
```

This is buildSql:

```
def buildSql[T, A](args: T)(implicit sqlArgument: SqlArgumentBuilder[T, A], sp: SetParameter[A]): SQLActionBuilder = {
    sqlArgument.sql(args)
  }
```

I am not sure coproduct is the right way to go, what I need is to somehow find the concrete instance type without explicitly matching from it or something similiar

Comment: Does `cp` have to be a `PartialFunction`? Or is your goal just to have a generic method/function that passes its argument on to `buildSql`?

Comment: Doesn't have to be a `PartialFunction`, A generic function would be even better

Answer (score 1):

That is probably longer that you expected but I think that this is how it should look like.

So in method generic we get the generic representation of `SqlArgument`, which is something that is an instance of just one of the concrete subtypes of `SqlArgument`. In your case `LanguageCode :+: BlobHashs :+: LastSeenId :+: CNil`. To figure out of which type our instance actually, is we pass that generic representation to the `implicit` value provided by `coproduct` and we proceed recursively in a head tail manner.

In your case `H` = `LanguageCode` and `T` = `BlobHashs :+: LastSeenId :+: CNil`.
If our instance is of type `LanguageCode` it will match with first case.
If it is of another type, it will proceed recursively with the tail. That is `H` = `BlobHashs` and T = `LastSeenId :+: CNil` and so on....

```
import shapeless.{Generic, Coproduct, Inr, Inl, CNil, :+:}

trait cp[T] {
  def apply(t: T): SQLActionBuilder
}

object cp {
  def apply(a: SqlArgument)(implicit cp: cp[SqlArgument]) = cp(a)

  def pure[T](f: T => SQLActionBuilder) = new cp[T] {
    def apply(t: T) = f(t)
  }

  implicit def generic[Co <: Coproduct](implicit gen: Generic.Aux[SqlArgument, Co], cp: cp[Co]): cp[SqlArgument] = pure {
    sql => cp(gen.to(sql))
  }

  implicit val cnil: cp[CNil] = pure(_ => throw new Exception("Impossible!"))

  implicit def coproduct[H, T <: Coproduct, A](implicit cp: cp[T],
                                                        b: SqlArgumentBuilder[H, A],
                                                        sp: SetParameter[A]): cp[H:+:T]  = pure {
    case Inl(h) => buildSql(h)
    case Inr(t) => cp(t)
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time putting this down, I've tried using it like this:
`import cp._; val q = cp(PlaceIds(List(1,2,3)))` but I am getting 
`Error:(207, 13) could not find implicit value for parameter cp: net.findhotel.zedek.core.data.SqlWriter.cp[net.findhotel.zedek.core.models.Payloads.SqlArgument]
  val q = cp(PlaceIds(List(1,2,3)))` Which is weird since I see the recursive construct here that should expose this

Comment: @raam86 could you rerun it with either the `-Xlog-implicits` compiler option or with the [splain](https://github.com/tek/splain/) compiler plugin and post the full implicit not found chain here?

Comment: Thank you, that helped, it's complaining about sealed traits / case classes so I suppose I have to construct my solution a little differently in order for this to work